# TTL for collection using Doctrine MongoDB ODM

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am having hard time trying to figure out how to implement time to live for one of my collections.

I would really appreciate your help.

I have class token, which like the name says generates token for me, to authorize users. 
I am using yml mapping and I would like to set ttl for my collection, to make it expire after some time. But it doesn't work for me. I am using mongo version 2.4.9 so it supports ttl already, so it has to be wrong configuration fault.

My entity class:

Class Token
{

```
protected $id;

protected $token;

protected $createDate;

protected $user;
```

}

My mapping:

```
Token:
 collection: token
fields:
 id:
  id: true
  type: id
 token:
  index: true
  type: string
 createDate:
  type: date
 indexes:
  createDate:
   options:
     expireAfterSeconds: 30
   keys:
    expiration: true
 referenceOne:
  user:
    targetDocument: User
```

This type of configuration doesn't work.